# Stop sliding for some operation completion in swiper in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, swiper.js

I am changing contents of swiper slider after sliding. before changing contents it navigates to next slide.Can I stop sliding untill my api response comes.can anyone pls help me.below is my swiper initialization

```
   setTimeout( ()=>{  var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
direction: 'horizontal',
  loop: true,
  speed: 700,
  replaceState: true,
  initialSlide: 1,
  centeredSlides: true,
  slidesPerView: 'auto',
  loopedSlides: 2,
  keyboard: true,
  scrollbar: false,
  pagination: false,
  navigation: true,

  preloadImages          : true,

  roundLengths           : true,
  observer               : true,


onSlideNextStart:function(swiper){

  ChangeContents(swiper)
},

mousewheelControl: false
 });},3000);
```

Thanks